# Can't activate WiFi after fresh install

Tags: networking, drivers

I have installed the latest version of Kubuntu from a USB stick and I don't know why I can't switch the WiFi button to "ON" (it stucks on orange light), also there is no `wlan` interface in `ifconfig` output (same for `lspci | grep -i wireless`) . I've tried to look for wifi switch in BIOS setup but didn't find any. The wireless module in this laptop was working fine on previous system.

EDIT: Laptop model is HP Pavilion dv6, and everything in system is up to date

`lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    DeviceName:  Thunderbird2 1x1 b/g/n
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [103c:1629]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at c4400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Comment: Please, provide more details on your system setup, like brand, model, etc. Also, be sure to update the packages via Ethernet, with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Also, I can suggest to try with a LTS version of Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came across same problem, the solution is to reset BIOS settings to default.

Comment: Do you have more details about which BIOS settings in specific?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to reset all settings to default